# Spring validation. Не подтягиваются сообщения из message.propierties

Tags: java, spring, валидация

Всем привет! Решил разобраться с валидацией и прикрутить к своему учебному проекту проверку данных при регистрации пользователя.

Добавил в конфиг бин:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.test.project")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

...

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("resources");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

Создал в каталоге resources файл message.properties:

```
user.loginIsEmpty = Login is required.
user.login = Login must be between 8 and 16 characters.
user.duplicateLogin = Such login already exists.
user.passwordIsEmpty = Password is required.
user.password = Password must be over 8 characters.
user.confirmPasswordIsEmpty = Confirm password is required.
user.differentPassword = Password don't match.
```

Написал класс для валидации:

```
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return User.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        User user = (User) o;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "login", "user.loginIsEmpty");
        String login = user.getLogin();
        String password = user.getPassword();
        if (login.length() > 16 || login.length() < 8)
            errors.rejectValue("login", "user.login");

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "user.passwordIsEmpty");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "confirmPassword", "user.confirmPasswordIsEmpty");

        if (password.length() < 8)
            errors.rejectValue("password", "user.password");

        if (!password.equals(user.getConfirmPassword()))
            errors.rejectValue("confirmPassword", "user.differentPassword");

        if (userService.getByLogin(login) != null)
            errors.rejectValue("login", "user.duplicateLogin");
    }
}
```

Добавил проверку на валидность в контроллер:

```
@Controller
public class RegController {

    @Autowired
    UserValidator userValidator ;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/reg", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signUp(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "reg";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/reg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signUp(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        userValidator.validate(user, bindingResult);
        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            userService.create(passenger);
            return "/index";
        }
        else
            return "/reg";
    }
}
```

Добавил форму:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="passenger">
    <spring:bind path="login">
        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <form:input type="text" path="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Login"></form:input>
            <form:errors path="login"></form:errors>
        </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="password">
        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <form:input type="password" path="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"></form:input>
            <form:errors path="password"></form:errors>
        </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <spring:bind path="confirmPassword">
        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <form:input type="password" path="confirmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm your password"></form:input>
            <form:errors path="confirmPassword"></form:errors>
        </div>
    </spring:bind>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form:form>
```

Вроде все делал по туториалам, но, например, при пустом поле логина, на странице отобразится не "Login is required.", а "user.loginIsEmpty". И так со всеми полями.

Подскажите, где я ошибся?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При инициализации конфигурации `Spring` нужно указать, откуда брать настройки оной:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:resources/message.properties"})
```

Можно указать абсолютный путь (например такой):

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {"file:/opt/common_resources/message.properties"})
```

---

После этого создаете бин, который будет читать информацию из файла:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

---

Теперь можно объявлять переменные:

```
@Value("${user.loginIsEmpty}")
String loginIsEmpty;

@Value("${user.login}")
String login;

@Value("${user.duplicateLogin}")
String duplicateLogin;

@Value("${user.passwordIsEmpty}")
String password;

@Value("${user.confirmPasswordIsEmpty}")
String confirmPasswordIsEmpty;

@Value("${user.differentPassword}")
String differentPassword;
```

Или вот так еще можно:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource(
        @Value("${user.loginIsEmpty}") String loginIsEmpty,
        @Value("${user.login}") String login,
        @Value("${user.duplicateLogin}") String duplicateLogin,
        @Value("${user.passwordIsEmpty}") String password,
        @Value("${user.confirmPasswordIsEmpty}") String confirmPasswordIsEmpty,
        @Value("${user.differentPassword}") String differentPassword,
) {
    // Работа с данными
    // . . .

    return messageSource;
}
```

Comment: На мой взгляд для пути к свойствам лучше использовать "classpath:message.properties". Он найдёт их в папке resources

Comment: Попробовал предложенные вами способы, но проблема не прошла.

Сейчас при невалидных данных сообщения выглядит примерно так: "user.login.user.login" или "user.passwordIsEmpty.user.password".

Если в IDEA через CTRL нажать на третий аргумент метода ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "user.login", "user.validate.loginEmpty"), то переносит на нужное место в message.properties

Comment: попробуйте добавить бин в конфигурацию:
'@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:property.properties")
public class DevConfig {
 @Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer() {
     return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }
}'

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло. Мне кажется, что я что-то упустил. Для чего вводятся @Value? Надо ли проводить дополнительные манипуляции в классе Validator? Что вы подразумеваете под "// Работа с данными" в бине MessageSource (кроме того, что у меня там уже есть)?

Comment: Да, бин PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer я добавил

Comment: Мне кажется, Вы забыли то, что теперь эти проперти нужно брать из поля бина с ними. Т. е. Если у вас метод:ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "user.login", "user.validate.loginEmpty") то вместо данных строк там должны быть геттеры на соответствующие поля бина Message Source.

Comment: Да, действительно, этого я не сделал. Спасибо за подсказку, все заработало!